# What's about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-p_n u}$, where $p_n$ is the nth-prime number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, improper-integrals, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function

I am assuming that the following function, for which I am asking as reference request, should be known in the literature, since **Glaisher** studied the [Prime Zeta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function), and my computation is the first step of **Riemann's trick** for the deduction of the integral representation of $\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)$, for $\Re s>1$.

Then when I do the substitution $t=p_nu$, denoting $p_n$ as the **nth prime number**, for $\Re s>1$, in the integral representation formula for the **Gamma function** you get 
$$\Gamma(s)P(s)=\int_0^\infty u^{s-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-p_n u}du,$$
where $P(s)$ is the **Prime Zeta Function.**

> **Question.** I am assuming that I can do previous computation, since the integral is absolutely convergent? **Can you give a justification to do the change the signs of the series and the integral?** After, from a divulgative viewpoint, it is known the function 
>   $$\hat{\theta}(u)=\sum_{p\text{ prime}}e^{-p u},$$
>   or can you say where is defined, or some well known and easy  facts about this*? **THanks in advance.**

$*$ I say if if it possible know if such function satisfies a equation, or if it known how grows, limits or bounds (the only thing from previous link that I can deduce is that $\lim_{s\to1^+}\int_0^\infty u^{s-1}\hat{\theta}(u)du\sim\log \left( \frac{1}{s-1} \right) $, since $\Gamma(1)=1$, but it don't say nothing to me about $\hat{\theta}(u))$. Then on assumption that $\hat{\theta}(u)$ can be defined, I am assuming that it is known from the literature and you can do a short summary about the more important facts: **where is defined and some important fact about this special function, or a site where I can see those.**

Comment: The second part of my question is from a divulgative viewpoint, I say that I understand that isnt a geometric series, thus it is difficult compute things about this function, but perhaps by comparison with other functions you can state some easy facts. Isn't neccesary a lot of facts, only some relevants facts. Thanks.

Comment: For the change between series and integral, since everything is positive under your integral and sum, straight Fubini will justify it.

Comment: Then **the first question is answered from your words**, very thanks much @MJ73550 You or other user are welcome to explain it, if are neccesary (I believe that no) more details.

Comment: $p_n\geq 2n+1$ will give you a quite trivial upper bound

Comment: Very thanks much, I hope that myself is a good question and we obtain soon more answers, thanks @MJ73550

Comment: the poles/singularities of $\sum_n a_n n^{-s}$ are very related with the behavior of $\sum_n a_n  z^n$ at $z=1$ because of $\Gamma(s) \sum_n a_n n^{-s} = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \sum_n a_n  e^{-nx} dx$. start with $|a_n| < C n^{\sigma}$

Comment: Thanks for your patience user@1952009, yesterday I read how compute $\frac{\zeta^2(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ in a book, I know that I need study to learn your claims! But I need a long time to encourage to me.

Comment: you know that $\zeta(s)\Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1} dx$, what can you say from the fact that $\frac{x}{e^x-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} x^k$ when $|x| < 2 \pi$ ? (the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) )

Comment: what I meant :  that $\frac{x}{e^x-1} \sim 1$  when $x \to 0$ means that $\zeta(s) \Gamma(s)$ is holomorphic for $Re(s) > 1$ with a simple pole at $s= 1$ with residue $1$, that $\frac{x}{e^x-1} - 1 \sim -\frac{1}{2} x$ means that $\zeta(s) \Gamma(s) - \frac{1}{s-1}$ is holomorphic for $Re(s) > 0$ with a simple pole at $s=0$ with residue $-1/2$, etc.